# The counter counts strangly

Tags: counter, verilog

My code describes a FSM to control a traffic light. There are four states, each with a different
duration.

Whenever the counter equals 1, the counter needs one more clock to change to the next value.  For example, at state1, counter is programmed to count from 4 to 1. Every value should only take one clock to
change to the next, when it does, the state is changed to the next state. But when counter equals 1, it takes two clocks to change.

My program is as follows. The counter is implemented at the bottom of the always block:

```
module HW3(times,A,B,clk,rst,iHand,iChang,s1);

input clk,rst;
output reg [2:0]A,B;
wire oclk;//new freq
reg [2:0] count1,count2,count3,count4;//count times
reg  [2:0]times;
reg temp;//control the switch 
parameter [2:0]state1=3'd0,state2=3'd1,state3=3'd2,state4=3'd3;

always@(posedge clk or negedge rst  )
    begin 


                if(!rst)
                    begin
                        s1<=state1;
                        A<=3'b0;
                        B<=3'b0;
                        count1<=3'd4;
                        count2<=3'd2;
                        count3<=3'd3;
                        count4<=3'd2;
                        temp<=1'b1;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        if(temp==1)
                            begin
                                temp<=1'b0;
                                case(s1)
                                    state1:
                                        begin
                                            times<=count1;
                                            A<=3'b001;
                                            B<=3'b100;
                                            s1<=state2;
                                        end
                                    state2:
                                        begin
                                            times<=count2;
                                            A<=3'b010;
                                            B<=3'b100;
                                            s1<=state3;             
                                        end
                                    state3:
                                        begin
                                            times<=count3;
                                            A<=3'b100;
                                            B<=3'b001;
                                            s1<=state4;

                                        end
                                    state4:
                                        begin
                                            times<=count4;
                                            A<=3'b100;
                                            B<=3'b010;
                                            s1<=state1;
                                        end
                                    default:
                                        begin
                                            A<=3'b000;
                                            B<=3'b000;
                                        end
                                    endcase
                            end 
                        else
                            begin
                                if(times>1)
                                    times<=times-1;
                                else if(times==1)
                                    begin
                                        temp<=1'b1;//can't count averagely

                                    end
                            end
                    end

    end 
endmodule
```

Comment: Your code has many, many problems. [Read This!](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2003SJ_SystemVerilogFSM.pdf)

Comment: I have fixed the problem you said, but the delay still exists

Comment: I have it setup on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/8Ap). It looks like all of the states take an extra clock to transition. Add `state` and `times` to the waveform view.

Comment: Wow,you're such a good man!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Modify the code at the bottom of the always clock as:   

if(times>2)
 times<=times-1;
         else if(times==2)
                 begin
                         times=times-1;
                         temp<=1'b1;//can't count averagely

                      end
```

Just let the times counts to 2 ,because if let it count to 1, the program  will again enter the if

block in the next clock but doesnt change the value of times ,and make the value of times=1 unchanged

for one more clock